# How can I combine CakePHP's Auth helper with a second authentication method?

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I've been using CakePHP's Auth helper for a while now, and while it's been successful, recently I was asked to re-tool our system. We're to allow users to log in using their Active Directory credentials.

Actually authenticating users is easy, and I already have the code to do this. However, Auth itself is shrouded in mystery, and I haven't swam through it's source code yet. What I'd like to do is have the system attempt to authenticate using the standard Auth method, and if that fails, fallback on Active Directory and attempt to authenticate that way.

Database wise, I figure I'll need to modify my users table to store the Active Directory credentials in some way (something as simple as storing the AD username should suffice actually, since it's just a link) and then manually log that user in. Is there a way to just tell Auth that "Hey, I'm logged in as this user now" without doing a POST to login()?

The main reason I'm doing all of this is to avoid having to rewrite tons of code elsewhere in the project by switching away from Auth entirely. That may be a bad idea though, if I'm introducing some hidden insecurity that's going to bite me later.

Oh: We're using CakePHP 1.3. I'm not against upgrading the project to version 2.0, but I'll avoid it unless there's a good reason to.

Comment: for 2.0 there are very easy ways to do that. but for 1.3 I am stumped for an answer. In my opinion there are a lot of very good reasons to upgrade (one is this question itself, others are performance, bugfixes and more)

Comment: I may trudge through the update, but I had to modify core in my current build. (A nasty hack to get around an over-zealous mod-security install that wasn't liking the frequent "][" in Cake's field naming) I'm *certain* that will bite me when trying to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just call: `$Auth->login($user);` where $user contains the queried data. So if you have the Active Directory credentials associated with the user account record in the database, you can just do:

```
$user = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array({ACTIVE RECORD SEARCH})));
$Auth->login($user);
```

and now you are logged in as that user.

Comment: ...surprisingly, this may be correct. I'm investigating another approach that involves extending the AuthComponent class, but this looks a lot quicker to implement if it works. Will test on Thursday, I have the day off today.